# Selecting single value from dictionary with multiple values per key

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dictionary={'key1': ['value1', 3.20],
            'key2': ['value2', 5.10]}
```

What i want to do is pull out float values and sum them up so 3.20+5.10 but i can't find right method anywhere. I was told by my 'teacher' that it's supposed to look something like this: `print(dictionary.values()[1])`, it seems right but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: does your current code run? dictionaries are key: value pairs so you need `{'key1': [...], etc}`

Comment: `for item in dictionary.values(): ... item[1]  ...`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = sum(v for _, v in dictionary.values())
```

Equivalently:

```
result = sum(lst[1] for lst in dictionary.values())
```

This is functional approach:

```
from operator import itemgetter

result = sum(map(itemgetter(1), dictionary.values()))
```

If you're a novice and you prefer an approach easier to understand:

```
result = 0
for lst in dictionary.values():
    result = result + lst[1]
```

As you can see there are many ways to achieve what you want!

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a dictionary. This is in fact a Set.
A dictionary has a form of: {"Key": "value}
Try

```
dictionary={'key1':['value1', 3.20],
            'key2':['value2', 5.10]}
```